# Is it possible to use local SQLite db on web browsers

Tags: sqlite, local-storage

Is it possible to use local SQLite db on web browsers like Mozilla, chrome, IE and safari. I mean, can i use local SQLite db for web application. If No, please suggest the alternative local DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Add-on for Mozilla:
[SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

Comment: Can the visitor access my web application once i developed using SQLite Manager with out using this Add-on at their end..

Comment: No, the visitor won't be able to access web application on their system. Thanks

Comment: So i can not use SQLite for db for web application development is it?

Comment: You can use for local setup but it won't work at end user.

Answer (score 12):

Well, you can use SQLite for the Web-Browsers using this [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/)

which says

> sql.js is a port of SQLite to JavaScript, by compiling the SQLite C code with Emscripten. It uses a virtual database file stored in memory, and thus does’nt persist the changes made to the database. However, it allows you to import any existing sqlite file, and to export the created database as a javascript typed array.

However, there are certain more ways to store your data in your browsers' local database. You may use these:

1. Indexed DB - W3C Recommendation 08 January 2015
2. WebSQL - It is no longer in active maintenance and the Web Applications Working Group does not intend to maintain it further.

Although Safari does not yet support Indexed DB, but hopefully in near future it will be supported by all major browsers.

There are certain drawbacks in each of these databases
you can follow this link to get a detailed comparison -> [(Link)](http://csimms.botonomy.com/2011/05/html5-storage-wars-localstorage-vs-indexeddb-vs-web-sql.html)

Answer (score 2):

**SQLite Wasm**

It's now possible to natively use SQLite directly on the web using the npm library

`npm install @sqlite.org/sqlite-wasm` ([npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sqlite.org/sqlite-wasm)).

**SQLite Client**

Shameless plug, if you don't want to deal with workers yourself,
I've created this wrapper library that encapsulates the communication with the worker:

`npm install @magieno/sqlite-client` ([npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@magieno/sqlite-client))